# How to drop the first two rows of a PySpark DataFrame column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with a column of tokenized text, and I want to drop the first two rows of this column. Here's an example of the DataFrame:

```
data = [(["This", "is", "a", "sample", "sentence"]),
    (["Another", "example", "sentence", "here"]),
    (["One", "more", "sentence"])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["tokenized_text"])
```

It has schema like

```
root
|-- tokenized_text: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I tried to use the drop function as follows:

```
DF = df.select('tokenized_text').drop(*[str(i) for i in range(2)])
```

However, when I count the number of rows in tok_df, it still includes the first two rows that I tried to drop:

```
DF.count()
```

I get the same number of rows that is 3

Can someone help me understand why the first two rows are not being dropped, and suggest a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: .drop() is used to delete column not rows, if you want to remove un-wanted rows user .filter() or .where()

Answer (score 1):

The `drop` function is used to drop columns. Try using the `row_number` function and assign row numbers to the DataFrame. Something like this might be useful:

```
window = Window.orderBy("tokenized_text")
df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))
df_filtered = df.filter(df.row_num > 2).drop("row_num")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If it's okay can I ask one more question? After trying this suggestion I tried to print out the number of rows by df.count() but I am getting Session timeout error now. The data frame is so small yet I am facing this error. Any idea as to why this might be happening?